# Error drawing arrow in canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I write code but it's not run.
I have 2 tag canvas. When i change properties height of canvas < 100 then arrow hidden. And if i didn't write tag div before tag canvas its run normal. Thank you for support!!!!
Source code:

```
<body>
<div id="yendau">LOL</div>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="100">Brower of you doesn't not support Canvas</canvas>
<div>Yolooooooooooo</div>
<canvas id="d" width="500" height="300">Brower of you doesn't not support Canvas</canvas>


<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script langauage="javascript">



function canvas_arrow(context, fromx, fromy, tox, toy){
    var headlen = 20;   // length of head in pixels
    var dx = tox-fromx;
    var dy = toy-fromy;
    var angle = Math.atan2(dy,dx);
    context.moveTo(fromx, fromy);
    context.lineTo(tox, toy);
    context.lineWidth=2;

    context.moveTo(tox, toy);
    context.lineTo(tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle+Math.PI/6),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle+Math.PI/6));
    context.moveTo(tox, toy);
    context.lineTo(tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle-Math.PI/6),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle-Math.PI/6));
}

$('document').ready(function(){
    var count= parseInt($("canvas").length);
    for(var i=0; i< count; i++){
        var ctx= $("canvas")[i].getContext('2d');
        ctx.beginPath();
        //var x= $('#c').offset().left-15;
        //var y= $('#c').offset().top-15;
        var x= $('#'+$("canvas")[i].id).offset().left;
        var y= $('#'+$("canvas")[i].id).offset().top+15;
        var x1= x+100;
        canvas_arrow(ctx,x,y,x1,y);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
});
```

Comment: first thing is : always start a new path with beginPath

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the offset of the canvas when calculating x,y. In your case, doing that will quickly push your arrow off the canvas.

The canvas offset is useful when calculating the mouse position, but not useful when drawing on the canvas itself. That's because the mouse coordinates are always relative to the top-left of the page--not the top left of the canvas.

The top-left corner of the canvas is x=0, y=0. So just set x,y to your desired coordinates bases on:

- x increases from zero as you move rightward across the canvas.
- y increased from zero as you move downward across the canvas.

Comment: Thank you for support. But i have a issues.
I want to ask you any more.
I want arrow with text in one line but don't know what to do. Looking forward to your help.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you want to ask something different and unrelated, you should ask another question.